# (iOS) Why does AVAudioPlayer initWithContentsOfURL always fail with error code=-43

Tags: objective-c, ios, avaudioplayer

```
NSString *songNameEscaped = [songName stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];    
NSURL *songURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", @"http://somerootpath/Music/", songNameEscaped]];

NSLog(@"songURL = %@", songURL);
NSError *avPlayerError = nil;

AVAudioPlayer *avPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:songURL error:&avPlayerError];
if (avPlayerError)
{
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [avPlayerError description]);
}
else
{
    [avPlayer play];
}
```

If I copy the NSLog output from `NSLog(@"songURL = %@", songURL);` and paste it in safari, Quicktime plugin plays the files no problem so I know the URLs are valid. I've tried with `.m4a` and `.mp3` files and have tried removing the spaces from `songName` but not matter what I always get Error:

> Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-43 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -43.)".

But they are just standard `.m4a` / `.mp3` files created in iTunes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently AVAudioPlayer doesn't support streaming. Apple recommends AVPlayer for this although it is not as conveinient for finding things like current time and duration .

Answer (score 1):

Error -43 indicates an inability to find the data.  This could be because the url was in fact malformed, or because the server doesn't support streaming. You should try to pre-load the song data with an NSData object.

```
NSString *songNameEscaped = [songName stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];    
NSURL *songURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", @"http://somerootpath/Music/", songNameEscaped]];

NSLog(@"songURL = %@", songURL);
NSError *avPlayerError = nil;
NSData* songData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:songURL error:&avPlayerError];
if (songData)
{
    AVAudioPlayer *avPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData error:&avPlayerError];
    if (avPlayer)
    {
        [avPlayer prepareToPlay];
        [avPlayer play];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Error initializing data for AVAudioPlayer.  Possibly an Unsupported Format");
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", [avPlayerError description]);
    }
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Error initializing data for AVAudioPlayer.  Possibly Malformed URL");
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [avPlayerError description]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem yesterday. Turns out my url was wrong.
I had something like you here:

```
NSURL *songURLID = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d", @"http://somerootpath/Music/", songNameEscaped]];
NSLog(@"songURL = **%d**", songURL**ID**);
```

But, my songURL was of NSString type. My NSLog wrote it correctly but when I put %d in url it turn out wrong. I suggest you try to check out your AVAudioPlayer url again.

try something like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5343204/1050722) to see the players url.

Comment: Well [NSURL URLWithString:] should always return an NSURL object or nil so your first line should definitely assign songURLID to an NSURL. But then strangely you use '%d' for NSLog output which would designate an unsigned integer. I will check out the link though and see if it will help.

Comment: I know what you mean. I was surprised nyself that NSLog returned the correct value and it took some time until I figured that one out. 
Like I said, try if ([player.url isEqual:url1])
     {
         // file which is in url1 stopped playing
     }
     else if ([player.url isEqual:url2])
     {
         // file which is in url2 stopped playing
     }

Comment: even if I just use `NSURL *songURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://somerootpath.com/Music/song.mp3"];` which I know is %100 valid. I still get the error and avPlayer.url always returns nil.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try checking the targets on your audio file. I had a similar issue and fixed it by making sure that my mp4 file target membership check box was checked. I must not have checked it when I was importing the file originally.

Answer (score -1):

in Apple documentation

> An instance of the AVAudioPlayer class, called an audio player,
>   provides playback of audio data from a file or memory.
>
> Apple recommends that you use this class for audio playback unless you
>   are playing audio captured from a network stream or require very low
>   I/O latency.